# Meaning of decoupling representation from interface (c++)

Tags: c++, terminology

I'm reading chapter 2 of programming in c++ by Stroustrup. When he makes the transition from concrete types to abstract types he mentions the concrete is not coupled to the representation. So if the class Stacks changes in a significant way the user has to recompile.

But I don't see the difference with the case where Stacks is abstract and he uses the derived classes in the same way. So what does decoupling of the interface actually do? Why is it desirable in some or most cases?

Edit: the book is "the c++ programming language" special edition (2000). Chapter 2, p5.4. Sorry.

Comment: Sorry for being a stickler, but I can't find a book by that name. Which one is it, exactly?

Comment: @KristianDuske this http://www.stroustrup.com/4th.html

Comment: @KristianDuske "I think"

Comment: Could you put the example?

Comment: @jiggunjer it would also be useful if you could provide some info where we can find the section you are referring to. Which edition of the book and which pages?

Comment: Stroustrup has written several books on C++, none of them called "Programming in C++". There are books called "Programming in C++", but not by Stroustrup. Could you clarify exactly which book you're referring to?

Comment: And please, put one example code.

Comment: I can't find the example you are referring to in chapter 2 or anywhere else in _The C++ Programming Language 4th Edition_ maybe it was in an older edition. But he does talk about Abstract Types in chapter 3, section 3.2.2 page 65.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An interface defines the logical operations that an implementation must support to let the client code access some functionality.  For example, an abstract type supporting output operations might be:

```
struct Abstract_Output
{
    virtual void blocking_write(const char* p, size_t n) = 0;
};
```

Many different output devices could have their own implementations satisfying that interface.  For example, a minimal low-level TCP library might report once it's sent at least part of a message - telling you how many bytes were written - but may not support automatic re-trying until all of a specific number of bytes have been transmitted, however long it takes.  An implementation might look like this:

```
struct TCP_Output : Abstract_Output
{
    TCP_Output(const char* server_name, int port) : tcp_(server_name, port) { }

    void blocking_write(const char* p, size_t n) override
    {
        size_t bytes_written = 0;
        while (n && (bytes_written = tcp_.write(p, n)) > 0)
        {
            p += bytes_written;
            n -= bytes_written;
        }
        if (n > 0) throw std::runtime_error("incomplete TCP write");
    }
  private:
    TCP tcp_;
};
```

On the other hand, if you're writing to a `std::ostream` object, it will block until the exact number of requested bytes are written, so we can write:

```
struct Stream_Output : Abstract_Output
{
    Stream_Output(std::ostream& os) : os_(os) { }

    void blocking_write(const char* p, size_t n) override
    {
        os_.write(p, n_);
    }
};
```

You can then write functions that can work with any type of output object, using runtime polymorphism via the abstract class/struct:

```
void report(Abstract_Output& o)
{
    std::ostringstream oss("/--- REPORT --/\n");
    for (auto& x : stocks)
        oss << x << '\n';
    o.blocking_write(oss.str().c_str(), oss.str().data());
}
```

Calls are then possible with any implementation:

```
Stream_Output stream_output(std::cout);
report(stream_output); // report to std::cout
TCP_Output tcp_output("localhost", 9191);
report(tcp_output);  // write report to the TCP server listening on port :9191
```

Relating all the above to your questions:

> When he makes the transition from concrete types to abstract types he mentions the concrete is not coupled to the representation. So if the class Stacks changes in a significant way the user has to recompile.

[[ Please also quote his exact text, then we can see if you've misinterpreted it. ]]  What we've achieved by using an abstract interface is to not couple the functions like `report` to the concrete output implementations like `TCP_Output` and `Stream_Output`.  Functions like `report` can be put in their own header/implementation file and not need to be recompiled if some client code somewhere wants to call them with a different `Abstract_Output`-derived concrete output implementation.

> But I don't see the difference with the case where Stacks is abstract and he uses the derived classes in the same way. So what does decoupling of the interface actually do? Why is it desirable in some or most cases?

So - as above, only the abstract class needs to be seen by translation units providing functions like `report`.  Further, `report` can be used (after re-linking) to send reports to output devices that weren't even envisaged let alone implemented at the time the `report` function was written.  That's decoupling.

Comment: Thanks i think it's becoming clear. But the decoupling is achieved by inheritance, not the virtual function. So your example should still work fine for the report function even if Abstract_output had a normal virtual function? So it seems the virtual function only forces a programmer to use consistent names, but decoupling comes from inheritance, not abstract types per se?

Comment: Also couldn't you make report take generic input with a template, foregoing the need for inheritance entirely?

Comment: @jiggunjer: inheritance alone doesn't let the `report` function operate on the derived types - that only works because the `virtual` functions can be used to invoke derived-class implementation.  Try it and see for yourself.  Using consistent names is sufficient when templates are being used (i.e. parametric polymorphism / duck typing), but if you don't understand the reasons why runtime polymorphism is sometimes preferable to compile time, you should do some more background reading.  Google if you like, or try my "top" answer for an overview....